# How to login to multiple host

Tags: unix

My hostList file is having multiple no of entries like below and it is hard coded and i dont want to change anything in hostList file

abc13bc1a abc13bc2a abc13bc4a abc15bc3a abc15bc4a abc15bc5a abc19bc6a abc19fe1 abc20fe .......... etc etc etc................

My script usage is given below

**Enter the hostname** 
  abc13 
**Enter the hosttype** 
  bc

my script is able to login to abc13bc with ssh command after providing the input.

Now I want my script to login to multiple host if i give usage like below

**Enter the hostname** 
  abc13,abc15,abc19 
**Enter the hosttype** 
  bc

like i want to login to abc13, abc15 and abc19 "bc's" and fire some output. Is there any possbile way to login to multiple hosts in my script like above usage

Comment: Refer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers

Comment: @KaushikNayak i am not getting my answer for comma seperated hostname by referring the link ... My hostname should be like abc13,abc15,abc19 so that it will do ssh to all the boxes and fire some output. That is what i need

Answer (score 0):

Read it into a variable host_list and Loop through the comma separated values using `for`

```
read host_list
read host_type
for i in $(echo $host_list | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
    # call your ssh command here
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: after using the above for loop i am using ssh command  ssh -l ser $i "cd;ls-rlt " >output.txt    [Note: "ser" is the login]  and i am not getting any output. Could you please help me out?

Comment: You need to configure ssh to run non interactively without password input. Refer this link to configure it.  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id

Comment: i am using host=`cat hostList.txt` and in my script i am reading "host_name" as abc13,abc15 and "host_type" as bc or gc. and my hostList.txt file is having abc13bc1a abc13bc2a abc13bc4a abc15bc3a abc15bc4a abc15bc5a abc19bc6a abc19fe1 abc20fe.. so how to use for loop or if loop so that i will be able to login on multiple boxes after giving host_name and host_type and it will grep the box for hostList.txt itself and fire the output..... I am getting totally blank. Could you please help me out in resolving this @KaushikNayak